# Meeting Error when I install scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

[image]

The situations above is what i have faced with. Totally don`t get it

Comment: why not use `pip install scipy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install pip from the pypl database directly with just:

```
pip install scipy
```

or if you want a particular version

```
pip install "scipy==1.00"
```

you shouldnt ever need to install from a local drive